# ONKEYUP abrindo função em CONJUNTO com ONCLICK

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um input text.

Quando Clicar no INPUT "categoria" abre o campo #resultado, simples!
Quando digitar mais que 1 caracter abre o campo #resultado, simples!

O QUE EU QUERO: Que as duas funções funcionem em conjunto! OU SEJA quando clicar pelo "onclick" ou quando fazer uma pesquisa "onkeyup"

```
<!-- ONKEYUP -->
$("#categoria").keyup(function(){

var query = $(this).val();

if($("#categoria").val().length > 0){

$("#resultado").show();//
```

)};

```
<!-- ONCLICK-->
$("#categoria").click(function(){


 $("#resultado").show();//
)};
```

Comment: Mesmo assim editei para facilitar! Por favor retire que esta duplicada

Comment: Alh, mas o que você está querendo fazer já não é o que está feito? Ambos eventos exibem o elemento com id `resultado`, que você quiz dizer com "funcionar em conjunto"?

Comment: Retire o callback de `keyup` e o declare como uma função a parte: `function eventoComum(){var query = $(this).val(); $("#resultado").toggle();}` .Depois passe a função para os handlers `keyup` e `click` de forma que as duas compartilhem o mesmo callback: `$("#categoria").keyup(eventoComum);` e `$("#categoria").click(eventoComum)`.

Comment: Se clicar musta a div, ou no keyup mostra a div, pq vc não faz um evento só usando o .focus(), assim atenderia as duas coisas... a funcionalidade que vc quer está meio incoerente...